# jquery works only in single div

Tags: jquery

I tried to implement the Hover effect for images just like Google Images in my site http://windows7themer.com but its working only in the first div section.

That page has around 5 repeated div sections. And also I want to resize the image to variable size as in google images.

Here is the original jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/HmTrw/

```
// ibox image zoomer plugin // roXon

(function($) {
    $.fn.ibox = function() {

        // set zoom ratio //
        resize = 20;
        ////////////////////
        var img = this;
        img.parent().append('<div id="ibox" />');
        var ibox = $('#ibox');
        var elX = 0;
        var elY = 0;

        img.each(function() {
            var el = $(this);

            el.mouseenter(function() {
                ibox.html('');
                var elH = el.height();
                elX = el.position().left - 6; // 6 = CSS#ibox padding+border
                elY = el.position().top - 6;
                var h = el.height();
                var w = el.width();
                var wh;
                checkwh = (h < w) ? (wh = (w / h * resize) / 2) : (wh = (w * resize / h) / 2);

                $(this).clone().prependTo(ibox);
                ibox.css({
                    top: elY + 'px',
                    left: elX + 'px'
                });

                ibox.stop().fadeTo(200, 1, function() {
                    $(this).animate({top: '-='+(resize/2), left:'-='+wh},400).children('img').animate({height:'+='+resize},400);
                });
            });

            ibox.mouseleave(function() {
                ibox.html('').hide();
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jquery('.item').ibox();
});
```

please guide me in this.

Comment: you should write your example js script in jsfiddle.net for better explantion..

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/HmTrw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your website and the problem comes from your CSS:

```
media="all"
.grid-view, .list-view {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
}
```

you should delete `position: relative;` and it will work.

Also try to replace

`$(this).animate({top: '-='+(resize/2), left:'-='+wh},400).children('img').animate({height:'+='+resize},400)`

by

`$(this).animate({top: '-='+(resize/2), left:'-='+wh},400).find('img').animate({height:'+='+resize},400)`

Comment: Hi, Yes its working thanks.. But Why the image is moving towards left instead of zooming in its place as in google images.

Comment: Could be `$(this).animate({top: '-='+(resize/2), left:'-='+wh},400).find('img.size').animate({height:'+='+resize},400)` as well. Tell me which one works.

Comment: I tried editing the CSS. But its not working properly still. Both of your above codes does resize image a bit. I guess the image resizes based on the inner div .hoverimg and not for .ibox.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you'll have to fiddle with the CSS. I'm sorry but I'm no expert. I hope you'll get the answer. If you do find it yourself, please do post it here as it will help people with the same problem. Nice site by the way.

Comment: I have almost done that.. Edited the CSS by defining separate CSS for ibox div.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. You really guided me well.. Just one help i would need. Before i applied this image hover effect, I had another jquery hover effect for displaying "Title, number of views and author name" Now its not working because of this new effect. can i make both of them to work together?

Comment: Checked your website and this information is still there. It's just hidden by the image. Applying a z-index could help to see them but I'm afraid they won't resize nicely with the image. Maybe you could do some tests with other jQuery plugins as the code you're using doesn't seem appropriate for images embedded in div.

Comment: Where should i add z-index for displaying those details?

Comment: I was using opacity:0; for that div section which was hidden. Now its fixed. Thanks for your support.. Take care :)